# Event receiver for new content types?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have played around with Event Receivers, they work well for new document additions and was hoping to manipulate the ListTemplateId to point to the Content Type collection but as far as I can tell that's not supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx).

My question is, is there a good way to receive new content type notifications? The intent is to notify the rest of the non-sharepoint services in the solution by publishing an event on our service bus.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Sharepoint auditing to accomplish this.

See how to enable auditing for content types [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx) (Blogspot - details for content types).

See [here](http://sharepointthomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in.html) for pointers on accessing the audit log. Sharepoint allows you to create your own events at this level as well.

Any questions, post again :)